# How to make ProgressBar of style large Thinner in width android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar

I have the mic icon and surrounding the mic icon, I need to place the Progress Bar to handle some running process like below:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_mic_movable"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_assist"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

The above code shows the UI as follows:

[image]

I want to show the progress bar like this, But this progress is very Thick. How to make it somewhat thinner with only 1dp?

Comment: Check https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 11):

None of the above answers worked for me. Struggling around found a below working solution.

progressbar_circular.xml. Use android:thicknessRatio for thickness of the circle. More the value will be, thinner it will be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="40"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="@color/color_black"
            android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Progress bar layout will be like below:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_circular"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: Hi where did you get this info from ?? I would like to get information about this doc please

Answer (score 3):

Here is custom `ProgressBar`. You can set thickness of progress inside shape.

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" //updated line
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"            //updated line
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_foreground"
        />
```

**circle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.2"
android:thickness="5dp"
android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="#ABBAC2" />

</shape>
```

**circle_progress_foreground.xml**

Change `android:thickness` as per your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.7"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="2dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <solid android:color="#fbcb09" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: I tried your code. The result is not as per the requirement. The progress is not running. It is appearing in the left most position.

Comment: it's an idea, you can achieve like this.you have to change alignment of `progressbar`. see update answer!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this below style on your xml progessBar layout,

```
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"
```

**Update**

try to add this property:

```
android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
```

Comment: I tried but it is giving some different progress bar then my requirement. So I tried style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse". But the result was same. I also tried setting fixed dp to wrap content, But then progress bar is not setting exactly around the image.

Comment: I need to make the progress bar looks thinner. It is very thick.

Comment: so you need thinker line progress in progressbar. right?

Comment: Yes thinner line progress

Comment: have you tried maxHeight and minHeight as property of progressBar?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by adding mimimum width and height

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:minHeight="5dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:progress="1" />
```